#  wordpress - find last anchor tag in post content and show text after that

Tags: javascript

I have a site whose content is appearing in this format:

```
<div id='foo'>
  <ul>
   <li>
      <a href=""></a>
      <a href=""></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
   <ul>
    <li>
       <a href=""></a>
       <a href=""></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    some text
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to find the last anchor tag and if that exists, then I want to grab the content appearing after the last anchor tag and display it in a div. The expected result/html which I want from above example is:

```
<ul>
    some text
</ul>
```

What is the best way to do this?